# Replacing a word with input through regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string `Pigs __(cant)__ fly.` I want to replace the word `__( )__` with an input field. What is the regex for this? I can do very simple regex stuff but this is going up above my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var str = "Pigs __(2cansf33't)__ fly"

var convertedString = str.replace(/\s__\(([a-z0-9']*)\)__\s/, ' '); 

console.log(convertedString)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: your soln works but how will it handle spaces in front or back of `cant` or numbers  or characters like `cant't `

Comment: `[a-z0-9']` inside square brackets you can add as much special characters you want to exclude